# Check string for specific number [Java]

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to check a string for a specific number but it doesn't seem to find it.

```
string = sc.next();

if(string != "-1")
 return 0;
```

So when I enter -1 into the input, it just continues on without breaking the program. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `!=` you need to use the operator NOT `!` and the method `equals`

So

```
string = sc.next();

if (!string.equals("-1")) 
   return 0;
```

Remember infact that the operators `==` (or `!=`) check for same (or not same) object. Instead `equals` method check that the internal value of the string is the same of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting a number I would read a number.

```
int num = sc.nextInt();

if (num != -1) return 0;
```

BTW: When you use `==` or `!=` for String it compares only the references, not the contents of the Strings.